# How to pick among 2 condition when both exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a condition. I want to group all employees by current designation i.e. 3 or by there initial designation i.e 1. but there could be a condition where both can happen because a person can have initial job record and current so i just want to pick current then.

1 = Initial
3 = Current

I tried but cannot do :(

```
Select Count(pi.pk_PersonalInfo_ID) as TotalEmployees, dsg.Name as Desgination from PersonalInfo pi
        Inner Join ServiceInfo si
        ON si.fk_PersonalInfo_ServiceInfo_PID= pi.pk_PersonalInfo_ID
        Inner Join setup.Designation dsg
        ON dsg.DesignationID= si.Designation_ID
        where si.ServiceInfoJobStatus= 3 OR si.ServiceInfoJobStatus= 1
        group by dsg.Name
```

this doesn't work properly.

For example: I have records of employees. Each employee can have more than one job record i.e. for INITIAL job, CURRENT Job. I want to pick his current job only when both initial and current exist.

Comment: Please read [Tips for asking a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2835541).

Comment: Add example data and expected output

Comment: Also, how it isn't work? Do you receive an error or do you receive wrong results?

Comment: @BozhidarStoinev no, but it picks both records. In this case i want to pick only current i.e. 3.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should always provide an example data set when asking SQL questions. In your case, I can make a fairly good guess that will at least put you on the right track.

You need to use an aggregate or windowing function here. Something like this should work.

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT pi.pk_PersonalInfo_ID) AS TotalEmployees, 
       Max(si.ServiceInfoJobStatus)          AS ServiceInfoJobStatus, 
       dsg.NAME                              AS Desgination 
FROM   personalinfo pi 
       INNER JOIN serviceinfo si 
               ON si.fk_PersonalInfo_ServiceInfo_PID = pi.pk_PersonalInfo_ID 
       INNER JOIN setup.designation dsg 
               ON dsg.DesignationID = si.Designation_ID 
WHERE  si.ServiceInfoJobStatus IN ( 1, 3 ) 
GROUP  BY dsg.NAME
```